# The method 'toDouble' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toDouble()

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, dart, querybuilder

---

**Buenas Noches con todos. ya he intentado de varias maneras corregir este error pero no he podido.**

ya he intentado cambiando el if por if(!snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.documents !=null)

etc.

También en el builder: intenté cambiarlo por builder:(context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot)

**Si alguien puede ayudarme le estaría muy agradecido**

El código funcionó perfectamente en otro ejercicio pero ahora que lo aplico a mi caso me sale este error.

se me hace bastante extraño que en un ejercicio similar esto funcione  y cuando lea agrego más campos ya no lo haga.

---

[image: Captura del Error]

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
    import 'package:corpore/size_config.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return MaterialApp(
          title: 'staff',
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() {
        return _MyHomePageState();
      }
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Staff')),
          body: _buildBody(context),
        );
      }

      Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream:     Firestore.instance.collection('schedules').snapshots(),
          builder: (context,snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null && snapshot.data.documents     == null){
              return LinearProgressIndicator();

            }
            else{
              return _buildList(context,      snapshot.data.documents);
            }
          },
        );
      }

      Widget _buildList(BuildContext context,     List<DocumentSnapshot> data) {
        return ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          children: data.map((data) => _buildListItem(context,     data)).toList(),
        );
      }

      Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context,     DocumentSnapshot data) {
        final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);
        return Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0,     vertical: 8.0),
          child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
          ),
            child: Slidable(
              key: ValueKey(record.time),
              actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
              actionExtentRatio: 0.50,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  record.time,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    fontFamily: 'BalooMedium',
                    fontSize: (3.00 *     size_config.textMultiplier),
                  ),
                ),
                trailing: Text(
                  record.state,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    fontFamily: 'BalooMedium',
                    fontSize: (2.70 *     size_config.textMultiplier),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
               secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                IconSlideAction(
                   caption: 'Agendar Cita',
                  color: Colors.green,
                  icon: Icons.check_circle,
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Cita Aceptada');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
         ),
       );
      }
    }
    class Record {
    final String dnidoc;
    final String dniuser;
    final String lnameuser;
    final String nameuser;
    final String state;
    final String date;
    final String time;
    final DocumentReference reference;
    Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['dnidoc'] != null),
        assert(map['dniuser'] != null),
        assert(map['nameuser'] != null),
        assert(map['lnameuser'] != null),
        assert(map['state'] != null),
        assert(map['date'] != null),
        assert(map['time'] != null),
        dnidoc= map['dnidoc'],
        dniuser= map['dniuser'],
        nameuser= map['nameuser'],
        lnameuser= map['lnameuser'],
        state= map['state'],
        date= map['date'],
        time= map['time'];
    Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
    @override
    String toString() => "Record<$dnidoc:$dniuser:$nameuser:$lnameuser:$state:$date:$time>";
    }
```

Comment: dice que en la linea 68 del main está el error, cual es ?

Comment: Me da error en el fontsize, lo quité y puse un valor entero y listo ya no tengo el error ya funciona todo normal hahaha Gracias por tu ayuda.